# Use OPFS (origin private file system) inside chrome's extension service worker

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension

I would like to play with this new API by following the [example](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/file-system-access/#accessing-the-origin-private-file-system) . The basic setup goes with no problem, though it fails right after when I try to use `createSyncAccessHandle()` method. Changing it to `createAccessHandle()` yields the same result. Error I've got `TypeError: fileHandle.createSyncAccessHandle is not a function`.
Here's the code:

```
const root = await navigator.storage.getDirectory();
const fileHandle = await root.getFileHandle('Untitled.txt', { create: true });
const accessHandle = await fileHandle.createSyncAccessHandle();
```

Is there a way I can use this OPFS functionality inside chrome's extension? It fails inside a service worker as well as in a popup script (for example).

Note: the other functionality of OPFS (like `createWritable()/getFile()`) works well.

Comment: The documentation says "only usable inside dedicated Web Workers".

Comment: isn't a service worker a kind of web worker? if not, as far as I know, I can't create a web worker inside a web worker, can I?

Comment: 1) No, it's not "dedicated". 2) No, but you can use `chrome.offscreen` API and then create a worker inside (it's still in development, you can try it in Chrome Canary).

Answer (score 2):

### How to use the OPFS In general

As the OPFS is a System Implementation it is needed to understand how to do low level system programming in general you will never use the OPFS Directly in a Efficient way you need to be the Operating System. That means You Schedule Tasks aka Processes and you do not execute it in kernel Mode eg your background worker or your main window. So in both situations you will spawn a Worker Per Task / Process not one single that takes all tasks. I hope that  helps you to understand the situation and archive your goals.

module.js

```js
// worker class
export class OPFSWorker {
    constructor() { 
    const root = await navigator.storage.getDirectory();
    const fileHandle = await root.getFileHandle('Untitled.txt', { create: true });
    const accessHandle = await fileHandle.createSyncAccessHandle();
    }
    onMessage(event) {
        console.log("main to worker", event.data);
        postMessage({ type: "answer", data: "data from worker" });
    }
}

// class to worker
export const workerFromClass = (workerClassRef) => {
    console.log(workerClassRef.name, "to worker");
    const workerFactory = (self, workerClass) => {
        const worker = new workerClass();
        self["onmessage"] = worker.onMessage.bind(worker);
    };

    return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(
        [`${workerClassRef}
        (${workerFactory}) 
        (this,${workerClassRef.name});`],
        {type: "application/javascript"}
    )));

};

// or alternativ export combined 
export const worker = workerFromClass(OPFSWorker);
// Then use worker directly imported.
```

// main

```js
import { workerFromClass, OPFSWorker } from './module.js';
let worker = workerFromClass(OPFSWorker);

// handle messages from worker
worker.addEventListener(
    "message", (event) => console.log("worker to main", event.data)
);

// send message to worker
let message = { type: "question", data: "data from main" };
console.log("main to worker", message);
worker.postMessage(message);
```